# Tool to generate a documentation for an module

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am looking for a generator that can help me create documentation for a module / script (Created with Laravel & VueJs) that I developed. Can someone advise me or offer me a library that does?

Preferably this generator is free and available on github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use https://vuepress.vuejs.org ( Vue-powered Static Site Generator ) this library created by Evan You.

Comment: Have you onther tool to do same think? this one need nodejs  >= 8 I Have v6.10.2

Comment: you can check this https://docsify.js.org , but you better upgrade nodejs to LTS version 8.11.3. hope this is helpfull :)

Comment: I can do this upgrade locally only in one project or not?

Comment: No, nodejs will be upgraded globally in your local machine